# Layout issue with UIStackView with distribution .fillEqually is ignoring spacing

Tags: swift, autolayout, uiimageview, uistackview

I have a layout issue I'm struggling to fix. I have a stack view in a tableview cell and I am trying to programmatically add images with different layouts based on the number of images. There's one parent stack, that is created in the storyboard and then I add to this one imageView and one other stack with multiple image views in it. The second stack ignores spacing though, and I am not sure why. If I create the same setup manually in the storyboard, setting it to .fillEqually will respect the spacing. The images are also not equal heights. Any clue what I'm doing wrong? Thank you

```
extension UIStackView {
func addImages(fileNames: [String]) {
    subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })

    let images = getImagesFromFiles(fileNames: fileNames)
    let gap: CGFloat = 8
    guard !images.isEmpty else { return }
    
    axis = images.count >= 5 ? .vertical : .horizontal
    spacing = gap
    distribution = .fillProportionally
    
    func insertImagesInStack(_ stack: UIStackView, _ images: [UIImage]) {
        for image in images {
            let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            imageView.clipsToBounds = true
            stack.insertArrangedSubview(imageView, at: stack.subviews.count)
        }
    }

    let topImageView = UIImageView(image: images.first)
    topImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    topImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

    insertArrangedSubview(topImageView, at: 0)
    
    switch images.count {
    case 4:
        let secondStack = UIStackView()
        secondStack.axis = .vertical
        secondStack.distribution = .fillEqually
        secondStack.spacing = gap
        
        secondStack.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: secondStack, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 120))
        
        secondStack.backgroundColor = .blue
        insertImagesInStack(secondStack, Array(images.dropFirst()))
        insertArrangedSubview(secondStack, at: 1)
        layoutIfNeeded()
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

}

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to my world. My advice: try your darndest _not_ to use stack views. They are the work of the devil.

Comment: This feels like it might be related to vertical compression resistance on the images in the second stack view. The image views probably want to be taller than the space available based on their intrinsic content size and the stack view has to abandon the spacing to try and make things fit as best as it can. Are you seeing broken constraints in the logs? What does it look like in the Xcode view debugger?

Comment: Also, wild guess. Can you try setting the vertical content compression resistance of the images in the second stack view to something low like 250?

Comment: Thanks @GeoffHackworth, setting content compression resistance to 250 doesn't help, but there were indeed warnings about the constraints (I keep OS_ACTIVITY_MODE disabled because there's a lot of junk usually) and I didn't see them. It seems like it's a confusing mess so I think I will just do it in Storyboard. Thanks for helping me figure it out.

Comment: I feel you @matt, sometimes they can behave erratically. But they are pretty powerful also, especially compared to the alternative where you have to create everything manually and add a million constraints.

Comment: @CristianMoisei - hmmm.... this is what I get when I use your code as-is (well, implemented the missing `getImagesFromFiles()`:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kZX6.png - I set the "main" stack view background to green to see the spacing.

Answer (score 1):

You know first image proportions, add constraint to it's `UIImageView` height.

```
imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(
  equalTo: imageView.widthAnchor,
  multiplier: image.size.height / image.size.width
).isActive = true
```

Also you have used distribution `fillProportionally`, looks like it's wrong when second view have fixed width 120. Try `.fill` or `.equalSpacing`.

Also I doesn't see alignment. Is it `.fill`?

Comment: Actually the first image should scale based on the width of the second stack, that's why I am adding the constraint to the stack.

Comment: @CristianMoisei it's scaled with my example, isn't it? Or did you mean based on the height of the second stack?

Comment: No, I meant based on the width of the tableview's cell. so the second stack will always have a fixed width of 120 and then the first image will take what's left, will be less on an iPhone and more on an iPad for example.

Comment: @CristianMoisei, yes just like I have implemented. Are you calculating cell height or using automatic?